# SWIFT 2 - Sort Multi dimensional array by date

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift2

I am trying to sort my array by date, I have been trying almost everything but with no results.

This is the closer I got but I get a waring:

> Constant 'sortedDate' inferred to have type ()

```
var Names = [[String]]()

 Names = [
            ["aaa", "bob", "ccc", "26-10-2015 17:50"],
            ["aaa-1", "bbb-1", "ccc-1", "22-10-2015 11:20"],
            ["aaa-2", "bbb-2", "bbb-2", "01-03-2015 17:00"]
        ]

let sortedDate = Names.sortInPlace({ return $0[3].compare($1[3]) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })

        print("\(sortedDate)")
```

Comment: You are using the solution I gave you to your earlier question, but you have not accepted my answer. What's my motivation to help you now?

Comment: hey Matt I was going to accept it I was immerse trying out all the codes.. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is `String`, not date. Use an `NSDateFormatter` to convert it to `NSDate`:

```
let names = [
    ["aaa", "bob", "ccc", "26-10-2015 17:50"],
    ["aaa-1", "bbb-1", "ccc-1", "22-10-2015 11:20"],
    ["aaa-2", "bbb-2", "bbb-2", "01-03-2015 17:00"]
]

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"

let sortedDate = names.sort {
    let date1 = formatter.dateFromString($0[3])
    let date2 = formatter.dateFromString($1[3])
    return date1?.timeIntervalSince1970 < date2?.timeIntervalSince1970
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is working good however, how can I sort the dates in descending order? using '>' fails