# How to sort multiple class objects with date property in single array with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, singleton, nsdate

I have two class and I added both class object in same array and both class object have property `date` and below is my code:

```
protocol MyType {

}


class A: MyType {

    var type: Int?
    var date: String?

    init(type: Int, date: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.date = date
    }
}

class B: MyType {

    var name: String?
    var date: String?

    init(name:String, date: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }
}

var array = [MyType]()

let AObject1 = A(type: 1, date: "2015-11-04")
let AObject2 = A(type: 2, date: "2015-11-05")
let BObject1 = B(name: "Birthday", date: "2015-11-03")
let BObject2 = B(name: "Events", date: "2015-11-12")

array.append(AObject1)
array.append(AObject2)
array.append(BObject1)
array.append(BObject2)
```

All object are added into `array` successfully but I have no I idea how can I short it with `date` property.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: see this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729337/swift-2-0-sorting-array-of-objects-by-property) & [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357568/swift-2-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-date) , if you not get the idea reply here we will support you

Comment: final array you can sort with date using `array.sort { $0.yourdate < $1.yourdate }` else in place you can sort  `array.sortInPlace { $0.yourdate < $1.yourdate }`, dont bothering in instance array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the date property to your protocol:

```
protocol MyType {
    var date: String? { get }
}
```

Then you can sort the array with something similar to:

```
array.sort { $0.date < $1.date }
```

or sort it in place with

```
array.sortInPlace { $0.date < $1.date }
```

Note that the string format your using allows you to use lexicographic sorts to achieve date sorted order, otherwise you might want to store the dates as NSDates.